# Getting rotated image form server when it is uploaded

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

```
- (IBAction)grabImage{
    UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.delegate = self;
    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
    [ipc release];

}

-(void)imageuploaded
{

    /*
     turning the image into a NSData object
s    getting the image back out of the UIImageView
     setting the quality to 90
     */
    //MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    //hud.labelText = @"Uploading image ";

    //assume that the image is loaded in landscape mode from disk




    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 0.09);

    // setting up the URL to post to
    NSString *urlString = NSLocalizedString(UploadText, @"");

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    /*
     add some header info now
     we always need a boundary when we post a file
     also we need to set the content type

     You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
     as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
     */
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    // Create a image file name

    store *myStore =[store sharedstore];
    NSString *imagename=myStore.Emailaddress;

    /*
     now lets create the body of the post
     */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.png\"\r\n",imagename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);

    //[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];


    label.hidden=YES;

}
```

Comment: Making synchronous request in main thread? Are you shure?

Comment: Moreover, this is a question or some kind of "how-to"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code https://gist.github.com/1064652 for fix image orientation before uploading it to the server.

UPD:
Click to create new file, select Cocoa Touch, then Objective-C category. Then write FixOrientation in "Category" field, and UIImage in "Category on" field. Then click next and complete files creation.
After that, insert method declaration

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientation;
```

in UIImage+FixOrientation.h

and copy implementation from github to UIImage+FixOrientation.m file.

Next, add

```
#import "UIImage+FixOrientation.h"
```

to your class, were you work with image.

After that, replace string

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 0.09);
```

to string:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([image.image fixOrientation], 0.09);
```

Comment: It creates a lot of warnings like on imageOrientaion  and on size, can you please help me out in initialization of these things

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement from above just use this method in your class:

```
- (UIImage *) fixOrientation: (UIImage*) image {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp)
        return image;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, image.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, image.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
    }

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, image.size.width, image.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.height,image.size.width), image.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height), image.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
```